# Why amp-sidebar results in 'hiddenElementInfos' of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amp-html

I'm using [amp-sidebar](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-sidebar/) in my website and when I open/close it occasionally throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hiddenElementInfos' of undefined
    at oa (modal.js:228)
    at amp-sidebar.js:385
    at mutate (resources-impl.js:1093)
    at Zm (vsync-impl.js:461)
    at Vm.f.Qh (vsync-impl.js:417)
```

My website is server-side rendered and I'm using [`react-amphtml`](https://github.com/dfrankland/react-amphtml) version 3.0.0 for amp components. Below is the my sidebar code:

```
import * as Amp from 'react-amphtml';

const AmpSidebarComponent = () => (
  <AmpSidebar id="sidebar" layout="nodisplay" side="left">
    {/* content */}
  </AmpSidebar>
);
```

The error occurs in this amp function:

```
updateForClosing_() {
  this.closeMask_();
  this.mutateElement(() => {
    setModalAsClosed(this.element); // error is here
  });
  this.element.removeAttribute('open');
  this.element.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
  this.setUpdateFn_(() => this.updateForClosed_(), ANIMATION_TIMEOUT);
}
```

while `setModalAsOpen` opens a sidebar by adding `aria-hidden` HTML attributes. It looks like an internal amp error to me not related to my code but maybe I'm wrong. Below is the code for `setModalAsOpen`

```
/**
 * Sets an Element as an open modal, making all Elements outside of the page
 * hidden from the tab order and screenreaders.
 *
 * This is done by making other subtrees 'aria-hidden', as well as giving a
 * negative `tabindex` to all focusable elements outside the modal. When
 * opening a modal, the ancestry has `aria-hidden` removed any any `tabindex`
 * values within the modal restored.
 *
 * Note: this does not block click events on things outside of the modal. It is
 * assumed that a backdrop Element blocking clicks is present.
 * @param {!Element} element
 */
export function setModalAsOpen(element) {
  devAssert(modalEntryStack.every(info => info.element !== element));
  devAssert(isConnectedNode(element));

  const elements = getElementsToAriaHide(element);
  const ancestry = getAncestors(element).filter(
    n => n.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
  );
  const focusableElements = getPotentiallyFocusableElements(element);
  // Get the elements that are internally focusable, and have been made
  // non-focusable; we want to unhide these.
  const focusableInternalElements = focusableElements.filter(e => {
    return element.contains(e) && e[SAVED_TAB_INDEX] !== undefined;
  });
  // Get the elements that are externally focusable, and have not yet been made
  // non-focusable; we want to hide these.
  const focusableExternalElements = focusableElements.filter(e => {
    return !element.contains(e) && e[SAVED_TAB_INDEX] === undefined;
  });
  const hiddenElementInfos = elements.concat(ancestry).map(element => {
    return {
      element,
      prevValue: element.getAttribute('aria-hidden'),
    };
  });

  // Unhide the ancestry, in case it was hidden from another modal.
  ancestry.forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('aria-hidden'));
  // Hide everything else.
  elements.forEach(e => e.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true'));
  // Make everything outside of the modal non-focusable via tab.
  focusableExternalElements.forEach(e => {
    e[SAVED_TAB_INDEX] = e.getAttribute('tabindex');
    e.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
  });
  // Restore the focusability of everything inside of the modal that was made
  // non-focusable.
  focusableInternalElements.forEach(e => {
    devAssert(e[SAVED_TAB_INDEX] !== undefined);
    restoreAttributeValue(e, 'tabindex', e[SAVED_TAB_INDEX]);
  });

  modalEntryStack.push({
    element,
    hiddenElementInfos,
    focusableExternalElements,
    focusableInternalElements,
  });
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm using `styled-system` version 5.0.16 and `styled-components` version 4.3.2.

Comment: you must use `Amp.AmpSidebarComponent ` instead of `AmpSidebarComponent `